# Removing a single element from a jQuery Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I am building a quiz game which contains different question types. One of these is an anagaram, so the letters have to be rearranged into the correct order. To achive this I am using 3 jQuery arrays, one contains the letters in the original order, the other contains the letters in the users selected order.

When the user selects a letter, it needs to be added to the selected letters array, and removed from the randomised letters array. The issue comes when there are 2 of the same letters in each array.

The example which raised this issue is the work Terry.

When R is clicked, I only need one of the R's to be removed from the array and added to the other. How would I achieve this?

The arrays look like this:

letters = ["t","e","r","r","y"];
shuffled = ["e","t","r","y","r"];

and here is my code:

```
$(document).on('click', '.order .letter', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    clickedLetters.splice($.inArray($(this).text().replace(/ /g,''), clickedLetters),1);
    console.log(letters);
    console.log(shuffled);
    console.log(clickedLetters);
    $('.order p').empty();
    $('.keyboard .keyboard-row').empty();
    l=0;
    while (l < letters.length) {
        console.log(letters[l]);
        revealedLetter="";
        if (clickedLetters[l]!= undefined) {
            revealedLetter=clickedLetters[l];
        }
        $('.order p').append('<span class="letter revealed">'+revealedLetter+'</span>');
            // $(this).addClass('correct');
        l++;
    }
    s=0
    while (s < shuffled.length){
        if (shuffled[s].match(/[a-z]/i)){
            if (jQuery.inArray(shuffled[s],clickedLetters) == -1) {

                $('.keyboard .keyboard-row').append('<div class="anagram-letter">'+shuffled[s]+'</div>')
            }
            s++
        }
    }

    if (clickedLetters.length == letters.length) {
        alert('done');
    }

});
```

Thanks,
Sean

Comment: You need to add the relevant code you've already tried to your question, plus an example array.

Comment: provide the arrays, data and your current code that tries to do it

Comment: Question has been update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I already had it working, I had just placed the code in the wrong place. Here it is for anyone needing it in future:

```
clickedLetters.splice($.inArray($(this).text().replace(/ /g,''), clickedLetters),1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is(for a hypothetical array1 and array2):

```
array2[array2.length] = array1[5];
array1.splice(5, 1);
```

to put the sixth element of array 1 to the end of array 2, then remove the unneeded row from array1